How can I require that a GitHub contributor write a PR comment with certain text before the "Merge" button is enabled?
I want to prevent a PR from being merge-able until the PR's author creates a specific comment on the PR, something like "It's my turn in the queue".  This is so that they acknowledge that they've joined our team's Slack queue for merging into main.
I tried using GitHub Actions, with the following workflow located in .github/workflows/check-comment.yml:
name: Check PR Comment for Queue Message

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ready_for_review]

jobs:
  check-comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check for required comment
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      with:
        script: |
          const { data: comments } = await github.issues.listComments({
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            issue_number: context.issue.number,
          });

          const requiredComment = "It's my turn in the queue";
          const hasComment = comments.some(comment => comment.body.includes(requiredComment));

          if (!hasComment) {
            throw new Error(`PR cannot be merged until the comment: '${requiredComment}' is present.`);
          }

Per these docs, I thought this would work.  But when I add this to my main branch, it doesn't appear to take effect.
I also tried going into the repo's "Settings => Branches => Add classic branch protection rule" section, and checking the "Require status checks to pass before merging" checkbox.  But under the expected list of status checks, I just see "No checks have been added".
Am I missing a step somewhere?
Here's the repo.

Will a ready_for_review event ever be emitted for a PR that was never in draft status?

@jonrsharpe I'm not sure, possibly not.  But would that affect whether the action shows up in the list of available status checks in the settings page?

It won't be in the list if it has never been run, I don't think.

@jonrsharpe you were right- I created a 2nd PR in draft mode, then clicked "Ready For Review", and that made the status check show up in the Settings page as well as the PR's pre-merge requirements.  Thanks!  Feel free to turn your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Add it as an answer for all searchers that will land here
